# Only able to boot via recovery mode

Tags: boot, recovery-mode

I'm using the newest 18.10 and only able to boot by going to recovery mode and by resuming to boot from there.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to comment, so asking question here - Have you tried fsck in the recovery mode ?

You could also repair the boot after logging in -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```